# WHat is wrong with gmt-5 and gtm+5 timezone files in linux

Tags: time-zone, utc

I am in EDT time zone and I would like to use `GMT-5` to convert time to EST (`GMT-5` and `EST` should be the same I think). But `GMT-5` results in +5hr offset from UTC which I would expect `GMT+5` should be doing it. here is the showcase:

```
(base) ➜  ~ date
Wed Jun 15 11:08:20 AM EDT 2022

(base) ➜  ~ TZ=/usr/share/zoneinfo/Etc/GMT-5 date
Wed Jun 15 08:08:23 PM +05 2022

(base) ➜  ~ TZ=/usr/share/zoneinfo/Etc/GMT+5 date
Wed Jun 15 10:08:26 AM -05 2022
```

So `GMT+5` is equivalent to `EST` ?

Very confused

Comment: Also both gmt files exist on the system

Comment: hmm seems files are corrupted, I see different output here https://time.is/GMT-5

Comment: further checking shows it is the same on the server

Comment: EST is 5 hours behind GMT not ahead of GMT.  So no need to compare GMT+5 since that most definitely is NOT Eastern Stand Time. I would agree your timezone files are corrupt

Comment: it does, thank you! Another question would be where can I get say PST time zone without any mixing it with PDT. I am looking for static PST time zone